# How to fix 500 Internal Server Error using AuthConf in HTTPD?

Tags: server, apache2

This is a new installation. I used `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql phpmyadmin`

If i put the following code in my httpd config file I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Any idea why I"m getting this error? Is something wrong with my directory path or password path?

ThiI is httpd.conf:

```
 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
 Options FollowSymLinks
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 # AllowOverride AuthConfig
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Restricted Files"
 AuthUserFile /usr/share/password/.htpasswd
 Require valid-user
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your webserver error logs.  They should detail the specifics of the 500 error.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. That fixed it. The log said: "[Wed Mar 20 12:57:02 2013] [error] [client xx.yy.zz.aaa] (2)No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /usr/share/password/.htpasswd" i changed .htpasswd to .htpassword and it worked.

Comment: Well, there you go.  :P